# method get(int) is undefined for the type Set

Tags: java

I have written a piece of logic, where, my goal is to select random keys from the map. The map has been assigned as a `ConcurrentSkipListMap<Text,IntWritable> tuples`. Also, I don't have any industrial level experience with Java, so struggling to get over this.

The piece of code is

```
Set<Text> keys = tuples.keySet();
String randomKeys = keys.get(random.netInt(keys.size()))
```

I am not able to figure out the error statement: `method get(int) is undefined for the type Set<Text>`

Also, I have searched for the similar problem, and a solution do exist using `List`, but my key/value pairs are stored as `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, so not able to figure out this.

Thanks.

Comment: [The Interface Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't have a get(int) method. That is why you get `is undefined for the type Set<Text>`

Comment: There is no `get(int)` method for `Set` interface. This only exists in the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) interface.

Comment: Do I need to convert this Set into String?

Comment: You could use an iterator to get an element from the Set.

Comment: You can add the set into to the list as so `List<Text> list = new ArrayList<Text>(set);` (or use a diamond operator if your JDK supports it.

Comment: Can the map still be changing?

Comment: I tried that, but there's a type casting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't have a `get()` method. You could use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Also, it's [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt())

```
List<Text> keys = new ArrayList<>(tuples.keySet());
Text randomKeys = keys.get(random.nextInt(keys.size()));
```

Also, depending on your use-case I believe it would likely be better to [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) **once** and then iterate it (perhaps with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)) like

```
List<Text> keys = new ArrayList<>(tuples.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);
for (String randomKey : keys) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I have stored my tuples as ConcurrentSkipMapList, is it fine to declare it as List and ArrayList?

Comment: My answer is only copying the key references to a temporary data-structure for shuffling. Notice it calls `tuples.keySet()` when it invokes the `ArrayList` constructor.

Comment: Yes, it works. I have to return this List as Sorted, I think I can figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Set does not have an get() method, because its not array like.

you normaly can iterate through an Set with its iterator: set.iteraor().next()

The iterator interface implements the folowing methods:

```
public boolean hasNext()
public E next()
public void remove()
```

you can use it like here (in this case is an Set):

```
Iterator it = set.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{         
        String setText = (String) it.next();
        System.out.println(setText);
}
```

Comment: Set does not have a `next()` method either.